# how to change navigation url on async page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I have used the following script but it doesn't show the url of link.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/football_manage/form" class="loadpage">add</a>
<div id="right_side_contnet"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.loadpage').click(function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault() 
      $('#right_side_contnet').load(this.href) 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: What does "kills the url" mean?  What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to change the URL in the location bar?  You might need to use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) here.

Comment: could you please also show your HTML? maybe there is just a type ans you mean $('#right_side_contENt').load....

Comment: i want the url of the link in the navigation bar i.e http://localhost/ci_sports/admin/football_manage/form

Comment: Could you try alerting `this.href` to see if it is what you expect?

Comment: what is your `base_url()` function? you need to make sure the link itself is correct. And you can open browser console out of developer tools to see what is the error.

Comment: what does the echo base_url(); shows

Comment: Looks like you have a typo that might cause an error .. shouldn't  `$('#right_side_contnet').load(this.href)` be `$('#right_side_content').load(this.href)`

Answer (score 2):

Ajax navigation can't simply change the browser history, and this is actually what you are looking for I suppose. This can be achieved by making use of history API introduced in HTML5 either by

1. Manipulating the history manually by the history API. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history),  [html5doctor](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/)
2. Use well implemented third party libraries for manipulating history. I'd suggest [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) or [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)